# Which statistical test should I use?

Tags: regression, repeated-measures

For the following data set, which statistical data should I use to analyze this data?

For different birds, different types of songs were played, and response scores were recorded from pre-playback, playback, and post-playback periods.

For example,

```
Bird#/Song/Pre/PB/Post
3   1   0   0   3 
3   1   0   3   3 
4   1   0   2   0 
1   4   2   2   3 
1   4   0   0   0
```

Which statistical test would be appropriate to use on this data set?

Comment: What do you want to test? You need to be more specific

Comment: I want to test whether the different song type leads to different response scores across pre, playback, and post

Comment: It seems to me that you need to use ANOVA to test the differences (if any) between the means of pre, playback and post

Comment: How do I compare the different song types though?

Comment: You are right. I forgot about the song type. In this case I suggest you take a look at Multivariate regression which is used when there are more than 1 response variables. Take a look at this 
http://www.psych.yorku.ca/lab/psy6140/lectures/MultivariateRegression2x2.pdf